# Highcharts JS Library and links to local files

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Please see this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/

You can see that x labels are links to files identified by a complete URL.

I need those labels to contain relative URLs, I cannot use absolute URLs.

If you change one of those links, for example:

```
var categoryLinks = {
      'Foo': 'localfolder/localfile.html',
      'Bar': 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo+bar',
      'Foobar': 'http://www.google.com/serach?q=foobar'
};
```

the x label associated to the first point ('Foo') is no longer an html link.

Quite bizzarre but that's what happens.

Is there a more sophisticated way to have links with relative URLs?

Comment: Local files, as in located on your computer, not on the web?

Comment: Sorry, you are perfectly right. Files identified by relative URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `useHTML: true`for labels, see: http://jsfiddle.net/y73RY/